# Kubernetes NodePort routing logic

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes setup that contains 4 minions (node1,2,3,4). I created a service that exposes port 80 as node port of 30010. There are 4 nginx pods that accepts the traffic from above service. However distribution of pods among nodes may vary. For example node 1 has 2 pods, node 2 has 1 pod and node 3 has 1 pod. Node 4 doesn't have any pod deployed. My requirement is, whenever I send a request to node1:30010 it should hit only 2 pods on node 1 and it should not hit other pods. Traffic should be routed to other nodes if and only if there is no pod in local node. For example node4 may have to route requests to node4:30010 to other nodes because it has no suitable pod deployed on it. Can I facilitate this requirement by changing configurations of kube-proxy?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, no. Hitting node1:30010 will pass traffic to the service, the service will then round robin the response.

Kubernetes is designed as a layer of abstraction above nodes, so you don't have to worry about where traffic is being sent, trying to control which node traffic goes to goes against that idea.

Could you explain your end goal? If your different pods are serving different responses then you may want to create more services, or if you are worried about latency and want to serve traffic from the node closest to the user you may want to look at [federating your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/federation/).

Comment: By round-robin the response do you mean that it will serve response from a random Pod which is assigned to a given service?